Calling an API on my local machine from within a container only works at first load
I'm running a Nuxt app inside a Docker container that talks to my local machine Laravel API on localhost:8000. I've followed this answer to make the container see my localhost.
docker-compose
extra_hosts:
  - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'

.env
NUXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL="http://host.docker.internal:8000"

Although The initial page load works, the subsequent link clicks fail with a 404 error as the browser send the requests to http://host.docker.internal:8000/api/some-api-endpoint and don't find it.
Using --network=host wouldn't work as I'm using Windows.
I've also read that mapping host.docker.internal to 127.0.0.1 in my local machine hosts file is not recommended and may cause errors.
